# Python Pygame Personal Module Error

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, runtime-error

So I was cleaning up my code by adding in classes, in order to put certain tools that I will be using in my game, into other files. SO as I was kinda learning and implementing, I stumbled upon an easy error that I can't find out for the life of me.

So I have my ***core.py*** and ***pyWMouse.py*** in the same folder. My ***pyWMouse.py*** just has my mouse tools that I created. I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Python/pygameDevelopment/core.py", line 115, in <module>
    game_Loop()
  File "G:/Python/pygameDevelopment/core.py", line 100, in game_Loop
    if userMouse.MouseLeftClickDown and userMouse.MouseDrag:
AttributeError: type object 'MouseTools' has no attribute 'MouseLeftClickDown'
```

Here is the class in ***pyWMouse.py***

```
import pygame
COLOR_RED = (255, 0, 0)
class MouseTools:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MouseInitXY = (0, 0)
        self.MouseFinalXY = (0, 0)
        self.MouseLeftClickDown = False
        self.MouseRightClickDown = False
        self.MouseDrag = False
        self.CharacterSelected = False
        self.CharacterMove = False
        self.CharacterMoveTo = (0, 0)
    def selection(self, screen, unitX, unitY):
        # Draw lines #
        pygame.draw.lines(screen, COLOR_RED, True, ((self.MouseInitXY[0], self.MouseInitXY[1]),
                                                    (self.MouseFinalXY[0], self.MouseInitXY[1]),
                                                    (self.MouseFinalXY[0], self.MouseFinalXY[1]),
                                                    (self.MouseInitXY[0], self.MouseFinalXY[1])), 3)
        # Check if anything is inside the selection area from any direction the mouse highlights #
        if unitX >= self.MouseInitXY[0] and unitX <= self.MouseFinalXY[0] and unitY >= \
                self.MouseInitXY[1] and unitY <= self.MouseFinalXY[1]:
            return True
        elif unitX <= self.MouseInitXY[0] and unitX >= self.MouseFinalXY[0] and unitY <= \
                self.MouseInitXY[1] and unitY >= self.MouseFinalXY[1]:
            return True
        elif unitX >= self.MouseInitXY[0] and unitX <= self.MouseFinalXY[0] and unitY <= \
                self.MouseInitXY[1] and unitY >= self.MouseFinalXY[1]:
            return True
        elif unitX <= self.MouseInitXY[0] and unitX >= self.MouseFinalXY[0] and unitY >= \
                self.MouseInitXY[1] and unitY <= self.MouseFinalXY[1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

And finally my ***core.py***

```
import pygame
import pyWMouse
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('PyWorld')
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 1080
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 920
COLOR_BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
COLOR_BROWN = (100, 50, 0)
COLOR_GREEN = (0, 102, 0)
COLOR_RED = (255, 0, 0)
COLOR_WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Character:
    def __init__(self, XPos, YPos): # Always called when object is created, always have self variable #
        self.X = XPos
        self.Y = YPos
        self.ImageUnselected = pygame.image.load('mainChar.png')
        self.ImageSelected = pygame.image.load('mainCharSelected.png')
        self.Speed = 2.5
        self.YChange = 0
        self.XChange = 0
    def render_Unselected(self):
        screen.blit(self.ImageUnselected, (self.X, self.Y))
    def render_Selected(self):
        screen.blit(self.ImageSelected, (self.X, self.Y))

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, XPos, YPos):
        self.X = XPos
        self.Y = YPos
        self.ImageUnselected = pygame.image.load('worker.png')
        self.ImageSelected = pygame.image.load('workerSelected.png')
    def worker_Unselected(self):
        screen.blit(self.ImageUnselected, (self.X, self.Y))
    def worker_Selected(self):
        screen.blit(self.ImageSelected, (self.X, self.Y))

character = Character(DISPLAY_WIDTH/2, DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2)
userMouse = pyWMouse.MouseTools
def game_Loop():

    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit:
        screen.fill(COLOR_BROWN)

        # Keyboard Handling #
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            character.YChange = -character.Speed
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            character.XChange = -character.Speed
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            character.YChange = character.Speed
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            character.XChange = character.Speed
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            character.XChange = (-character.Speed/1.5)
            character.YChange = (-character.Speed/1.5)
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and keys_pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            character.XChange = (-character.Speed / 1.5)
            character.YChange = (character.Speed / 1.5)
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            character.XChange = (character.Speed / 1.5)
            character.YChange = (character.Speed / 1.5)
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            character.XChange = (character.Speed / 1.5)
            character.YChange = (-character.Speed / 1.5)

        # Event handling #
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key != pygame.K_a or event.key != pygame.K_d:
                    character.XChange = 0
                if event.key != pygame.K_w or event.key != pygame.K_s:
                    character.YChange = 0

            # Mouse Handling #
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if userMouse.CharacterSelected:
                    userMouse.CharacterSelected = False
                if event.button == 1:
                    userMouse.MouseLeftClickDown = True
                    userMouse.MouseInitXY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if event.button == 2:
                    userMouse.MouseRightClickDown = True
                    userMouse.CharacterMoveTo = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                userMouse.MouseDrag = True
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if userMouse.MouseLeftClickDown:
                    userMouse.MouseLeftClickDown = False
                    userMouse.MouseDrag = False
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        # Mouse Tools #
        if userMouse.MouseLeftClickDown and userMouse.MouseDrag:
            userMouse.MouseFinalXY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Check if user's character is inside selection tool #
            if userMouse.selection(screen, character.X, character.Y):
                character.render_Selected()
            else:
                character.render_Unselected()
        else:
            character.render_Unselected()

        # Update Display and next frame variables #
        character.X += character.XChange
        character.Y += character.YChange
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(144)
game_Loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Thanks for your time everyone. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem can be found in *core.py*. Try changing :

```
userMouse = pyWMouse.MouseTools
```

to the following:

```
userMouse = pyWMouse.MouseTools()
```

Adding the missing parentheses should do the trick.